# align views to mimick an math integral expression

Tags: android, layout, view, android-relativelayout

I want to have a complex arrangement of views which should look like this eventually

```
 ______________
 | upper limit|
 ==============
      ____
      |  |
      |  | ___________
      |  | |Integrand|
      |  | ===========
      ====
    ________
    | low  |
    ========
```

Of course, I tried the obious things. The three views below each other, layout_centerHorizontal, puts them nicely centered, however with respect to the entire layout.

I want to have the view with the Integrand move inwards to the right of the long vertical view. However, the central alignment of the other views makes it impossible to achieve this.

If I center align the three views below each other in a separate layout, the fourth view will be too far away from the long vertical view, if the upper limit and lower limit views become large.

I assume that there is a simple trick to achieve it and your help is highly appreciated.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<com.example.nestviews.InputView
android:id="@+id/sum_upperlimit"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="10" />
<com.example.nestviews.LabelView
android:id="@+id/sum_label"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="-10dp"
android:layout_below="@id/sum_upperlimit"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:textSize="40dp"
android:text="\u2211" />
<com.example.nestviews.InputView
android:id="@+id/sum_function"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sum_label"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sum_label"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
android:text="n^2+1" />
<com.example.nestviews.InputView
android:id="@+id/sum_lowerlimit"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_below="@id/sum_label"
android:text="n=1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How about creating you own custom `ViewGroup`? There is some info on that on the Android Developers website: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: I still hope that I can avoid it. But thank you for pointing out this reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a relative layout inside a relative layout and an anchor for this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/sum_upperlimit"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View01"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/View01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sum_upperlimit" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sum_label"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sum_function"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/anchor"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
    </RelativeLayout>
     <View
        android:id="@+id/sum_lowerlimit"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works a bit better now. But there is still the issue, if the sum_label view is an editview, it will not grow beyound the extention of the inner relative layout. Moreover, there is space wasted on the left side of the view, since the views are still centered inside the view, instead of just being center aligned with respect to each other.